# Query for Number of Messages in Mule ESB VM Queue

Tags: mule

In a Mule flow, I would like to add an Exception Handler that forwards messages to a "retry queue" when there is an exception. However, I don't want this retry logic to run automatically. Instead, I'd rather receive a notification so I can review the errors and then decide whether to retry all messages in the queue or not.

I don't want to receive a notification for every exception. I'd rather have a scheduled job that runs every 15 minutes and checks to see if there are messages in this retry queue and then only send the notification if there are.

Is there any way to determine how many messages are currently in a persistent VM queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the default VM queue persistence mechanism and that the VM connector is named `vmConnector`, you can do this:

```
final String queueName = "retryQueue";
int messageCount = 0;

final VMConnector vmConnector = (VMConnector) muleContext.getRegistry()
    .lookupConnector("vmConnector");

for (final Serializable key : vmConnector.getQueueProfile().getObjectStore().allKeys())
{
    final QueueKey queueKey = (QueueKey) key;
    if (queueName.equals(queueKey.queueName))
    {
        messageCount++;
    }
}

System.out.printf("Queue %s has %d pending messages%n", queueName, messageCount);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I am surprised there is not an easier way to do this. Having to iterate over every message in the store to count matching names is pretty inefficient. But only plan to run this flow once every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: That is the way it is by default. You could try and substitute the default `QueueStore` (backed by a `ListableObjectStore`) with one backed by a `PartitionableObjectStore`, using a different partition per queue name. That way, `allKeys().count` on the right partition would the message count directly.